# Find Maximum time value from list of time value

Tags: python, python-2.6

I need to find the maximum time value from the list:

```
num[2] = 2012-12-16 16:56:31
```

I have tried with following:

```
max =0
for num in list:
 if num[2] > max:
   max = num
print max
```

But it is showing error:

```
    if num[5] > max:
TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to int
```

Comment: what exactly is this? `num[2] = 2012-12-16 16:56:31` are you assigning a date to num[2]? if so, you should probably use a `datetime` object, or at least surround your assignment in `""` if it is a string.

Comment: You can't compare a `datetime.datetime` to `int`, but you can compare it to `datetime.datetime.min` (which is a datetime representing a long long time ago, even before any of your datetimes).

Comment: @Surya Gupta, you should also accept some questions

Comment: I have a list from where i am taking this value num[5] for your convenience i put the value 2012-12-16 16:56:31 so that you will aware what type of value i am taking. While comparing with max showing error. I tried with num[5].min() > max still showing error "TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object is not callable"

Answer (score 3):

You can do

```
max(my_dates)
```

Don't call your list, list, as that shadows a builtin and makes confusing errors later on.

Don't name your variables anything in this [link](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html)

Comment: +1, (and OP should not call a variable `max` for the same reasons)